# There is 80 years or there are 80 years?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

Which one should I use? Do I use plural form of are since there is more than one year?

Comment: You should probably be looking at questions like [*Why do you say “Fifty miles IS …”?*](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13950/why-do-you-say-fifty-miles-is) on English Language Learners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a slightly unusual phrase, which leads me to wonder about context.

As put, "there are 80 years" is more grammatically correct, though you will sometimes hear people say "there is" even when the subject is plural.

However, "There is **80 years' worth** of research" is correct because **years** is not the subject of **is**, **worth** is.

Comment: There doesn't need to be an explicit alternative noun like *worth*. For example: *There **are 80 years** between when the King was crowned and when he died. But **80 years is** too long for one man to hold the reins of power*.

Comment: But 'There's 80 years of Elbonian rule after the great enswampment' rather than 'There're ...'.